# Passing many configuration options to Java code formatter

Tags: java, formatting

I use the DefaultCodeFormatter of the core Java package to prettify my code. Unfortunately I want to look my code very different from the default settings. That why, I have to explicitly define a lot of values:

```
public static String makeSourceCodeLookingMoreSexy(String source) {
        Map<String, String> options = DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.getEclipseDefaultSettings();

        options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_COMPLIANCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_6);
        options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_CODEGEN_TARGET_PLATFORM, JavaCore.VERSION_1_6);
        options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_6);
        options.put(DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.FORMATTER_ALIGNMENT_FOR_ENUM_CONSTANTS, DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.createAlignmentValue(true, DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.WRAP_ONE_PER_LINE, DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.INDENT_ON_COLUMN));
        options.put(DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.FORMATTER_ALIGNMENT_FOR_PARAMETERS_IN_METHOD_DECLARATION, DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.createAlignmentValue(false, DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.WRAP_NO_SPLIT, DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.INDENT_DEFAULT));
        options.put(DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.FORMATTER_ALIGNMENT_FOR_PARAMETERS_IN_METHOD_DECLARATION, DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.createAlignmentValue(false, DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.WRAP_NO_SPLIT, DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.INDENT_DEFAULT));
        options.put(DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.FORMATTER_ALIGNMENT_FOR_THROWS_CLAUSE_IN_METHOD_DECLARATION, DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.createAlignmentValue(false, DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.WRAP_NO_SPLIT, DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.INDENT_DEFAULT));

        final CodeFormatter codeFormatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(options);

        final TextEdit edit = codeFormatter.format(CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT, source, 0, source.length(), 0, System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        IDocument document = new Document(source);
        try {
            edit.apply(document);
        } catch (MalformedTreeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return document.get();
    }
```

That are not even all options that I want to set. Actually it is way more, maybe about 50. As you can imagine the code gets very long. So is there a better way to do this than I'm actually doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd extract it out to a helper method:

```
private static Map<String, String> getOptionsMap() {
    final Map<String, String> options = DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.getEclipseDefaultSettings();

    options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_COMPLIANCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_6);
    options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_CODEGEN_TARGET_PLATFORM, JavaCore.VERSION_1_6);
    options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, JavaCore.VERSION_1_6);

    // TODO: rename the variable
    final String aligment0 = DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.createAlignmentValue(true,
            DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.WRAP_ONE_PER_LINE, 
            DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.INDENT_ON_COLUMN);
    options.put(DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.FORMATTER_ALIGNMENT_FOR_ENUM_CONSTANTS, aligment0);

    // TODO: rename the variable
    final String aligment1 = DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.createAlignmentValue(false, 
            DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.WRAP_NO_SPLIT,
            DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.INDENT_DEFAULT);
    options.put(DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.FORMATTER_ALIGNMENT_FOR_PARAMETERS_IN_METHOD_DECLARATION, aligment1);
    options.put(DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.FORMATTER_ALIGNMENT_FOR_PARAMETERS_IN_METHOD_DECLARATION, aligment1);
    options.put(DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.FORMATTER_ALIGNMENT_FOR_THROWS_CLAUSE_IN_METHOD_DECLARATION, aligment1);
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(options);
}
```

Maybe you can split it up to two or more methods. The `aligment0` and `aligment1` variables should be renamed to a proper name. Note that you can reuse the `Map`, since `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` ensures that it cannot be changed by clients.